# HTML5/Javascript Code To Create Custom Picture from a Template

Tags: javascript, html, photoshop-script

Basically how do sites like picfont work? Or those cake design sites where you have a template and you insert your picture into the frame and add & stylise text to the textbox?

I have an invite ad for a programme, where people put their picture and name and send out a personal invite. So the graphics guy has done the template. Rather than having 1000 people send him their photos and names, I know it's possible to put the template on a web page and have people upload their pictures, do some custom edit and stylise their names.
HOW do I do this, please? I would like some pointers or code I can implement, please. Thank you.

Comment: Use the `<canvas>` element for this purpose.

Comment: @Zomry, please can you further elucidate? Can you please give a link? Or what's this called?

Comment: I'm sorry, I got confused on my end. I thought you wanted to do it in a web browser, but now I understand you want to do this within photoshop. The canvas element will not be relevant for that purpose. My Adobe CC-license has been expired for quite some time now, so I cannot help you out.

Comment: @Zomry, I want to do it in a web browser.

Comment: It depends on how sophisticated you would like this to be. Do you just want to show the picture to the user at that time or also post it on a server afterwards?

Comment: I just want to put the template on a web page and have people upload their pictures, do some custom edit and stylise their names.  Then they can download it and use it for their DPs on social media. I am not saving anything. Nothing complicated.. maybe just the ability to rotate or move their pictures to fit the frame on template; and also to choose colour and style of font for the textbox.

Comment: I will try to work something basic out to get you started. Might take some time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149303/discussion-between-aaa-and-zomry).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you will need the `<Canvas>` element for this, but this needs some custom development as well.

I took the liberty of creating a good starting point: https://jsfiddle.net/Zomry/f8to2fyq/11/

This demo loads a background image, can insert a custom image (assumed to be square here) and allows the location of custom text.

You can change this example to whatever you like. You will need to change the background, the positions of the text and the background and whatever you like to change with it.

Good luck with your project.